# Creating a JSONArray inside of a JSONObject in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have the following code...

```
 $mainResponse = array(
                 "result" => array(
                 ),
                 "ack" => "success"
            );

       foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
         $itemId = $item->itemId;

         $addThisItem = array("itemId" => $itemId);
         array_push($mainResponse['result'], $addThisItem);
     }
}

   echo json_encode($mainResponse);
```

OUTPUT:

```
{"result":[{"itemId":{"0":"183851233368"}}],"ack":"success"}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
{"result":[{"itemId":"183851233368"},...],"ack":"success"}
```

EDIT:

The response is received as XML. I use `$resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);`

```
$resp->searchResult->item
```

This is a list of items. Something like...`[{"itemId":"1"},{"itemId":"2"}...]` that contains everything I need. If I print `$itemId`, I get my itemId.

$resp...

```
<findCompletedItemsResponse xmlns="">
<ack>Success</ack>
<version>1.13.0</version>
<timestamp>2019-06-18T18:23:20.844Z</timestamp>
<searchResult count="1">
<item>
<itemId>183851233368</itemId>
<title>
2019 Bowman Mega Box SEALED LOT 4 Wander Franco Vlad Joey Bart TARGET Exclusive!
</title>
<globalId>EBAY-US</globalId>
<primaryCategory>
<categoryId>213</categoryId>
<categoryName>Baseball Cards</categoryName>
</primaryCategory>
<galleryURL>
http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/m/msMvr_Xz-51zlz4it4tOOLw/140.jpg
</galleryURL>
<viewItemURL>
http://www.ebay.com/itm/2019-Bowman-Mega-Box-SEALED-LOT-4-Wander-Franco-Vlad-Joey-Bart-TARGET-Exclusive-/183851233368
</viewItemURL>
<paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>
<autoPay>false</autoPay>
<postalCode>60098</postalCode>
<location>Woodstock,IL,USA</location>
<country>US</country>
<shippingInfo>
<shippingServiceCost currencyId="USD">4.99</shippingServiceCost>
<shippingType>Flat</shippingType>
<shipToLocations>Worldwide</shipToLocations>
<expeditedShipping>true</expeditedShipping>
<oneDayShippingAvailable>false</oneDayShippingAvailable>
<handlingTime>3</handlingTime>
</shippingInfo>
<sellingStatus>
<currentPrice currencyId="USD">104.99</currentPrice>
<convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="USD">104.99</convertedCurrentPrice>
<sellingState>EndedWithSales</sellingState>
</sellingStatus>
<listingInfo>
<bestOfferEnabled>false</bestOfferEnabled>
<buyItNowAvailable>false</buyItNowAvailable>
<startTime>2019-06-18T00:18:54.000Z</startTime>
<endTime>2019-06-18T17:29:04.000Z</endTime>
<listingType>FixedPrice</listingType>
<gift>false</gift>
<watchCount>3</watchCount>
</listingInfo>
<returnsAccepted>false</returnsAccepted>
<condition>
<conditionId>1000</conditionId>
<conditionDisplayName>Brand New</conditionDisplayName>
</condition>
<isMultiVariationListing>false</isMultiVariationListing>
<topRatedListing>false</topRatedListing>
</item>
</searchResult>
<paginationOutput>
<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
<entriesPerPage>1</entriesPerPage>
<totalPages>343</totalPages>
<totalEntries>343</totalEntries>
</paginationOutput>
</findCompletedItemsResponse>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well we don't know what `$resp->searchResult->item` holds so it's unclear.

Comment: its a list of items. nothing in there refers to a "0" at a key, or whatever.

Comment: From your code and description I made some assumption as to the incoming data and it works: https://3v4l.org/8JvJa 
So can you please check that data, and add it to question

Comment: @Dan thanks... my $resp comes in as XML. I use the following $resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);

Comment: It's hard to figure out when we also need to guess the input, because I don't see anyway, that code gives you that output unless the input is different

Comment: @Dan added the $resp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `var_dump()` to inspect values will help with troubleshooting these types of issues.

The problem is that `$itemId` is a SimpleXmlElement, and it doesn't get encoded in the way you expect. To resolve this for the particular case (could vary with different or more variable data) is to cast the value as needed.

`$itemId = strval($item->itemId);`

https://3v4l.org/j7meB

Comment: something so stupid!! where did you use var_dump? on $mainResponse?